# Type error: Module '"*.mdx"' has no exported member 'metadata'. Did you mean to use 'import metadata from "*.mdx"' instead?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, markdown

I want to get the metadata from mdx file.
and I followed this [NextJS Markdown Frontmatter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/mdx#frontmatter),
but it makes build error.

I can't use `fs`, so please note that.

## code

`Page.tsx` file

```
import ContentPost from "@/components/post.mdx"


const PostPage = () => {
  

  return (
    <div>
          <div className="  mb-8 md:mb-24 text-center">
            <h1 className="text-3xl">Title</h1>
            <p className="text-slate-400 mt-2">date</p>
          </div>

          <article className="prose mb-52 prose-emerald md:prose-lg lg:prose-xl dark:prose-invert">
            <ContentPost />
          </article>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

`*.mdx` file

```
---
    title: "Title",
    subtitle: "Sub",
    date: "2024-3-18",
    coverImage: "",
---

# Contents text
```

`mdx-components.tsx` file

```
import type { MDXComponents } from 'mdx/types'
 
export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    ...components,
  }
}
```

`next.config.mjs` file

```
import nextMDX from '@next/mdx';
const withMDX = nextMDX({
    extension:/\.mdx?$/,
    options:{
        remarkPlugins:[],
        rehypePlugins:[],
    }
})


/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'md', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    images:{
        unoptimized: true,
        remotePatterns:[
        {
            protocol: "https",
            hostname: "img.youtube.com",
        },
    ]
    }
};

export default withMDX(nextConfig);
```

## And I tried below.

```
export const metadata = {
    title: "Title",
    subtitle: "Sub",
    date: "2024-3-18",
    coverImage: "",
}
 
# My MDX page
```

In this case, I could get the metadata from the .mdx file.
And it worked perfactly on `npm run dev`.
But it caused this error when I tried to build.

```
Type error: Module '"*.mdx"' has no exported member 'metadata'. Did you mean to use 'import metadata from "*.mdx"' instead?

  4 | import Link from "next/link";
  5 |
> 6 | import ContentPost, { metadata } from "@/components/post.mdx";
    |                       ^
  7 |
  8 |
  9 | const PostPage = () => {


Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way myself.
But still, it’s not the answer to my question.

First of all, I didn’t know what frontmatter is, so I couldn’t use the frontmatter API.
After understanding that, I discovered the function I needed, which was `matter.read("md_path")`. Also, I had to change the `*.mdx` file to `*.md`.

To resolve this, I used two main APIs:

```
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx"
import matter from "gray-matter";

const PostPage = () => {
  const postObj =matter.read("public/post-contents/post.md")
  const metadata = postObj.data

  return (
    <div>
          <div className="  mb-8 md:mb-24 text-center">
            <h1 className="text-3xl">{metadata.title}</h1>
            <p className="text-slate-400 mt-2">{metadata.date}</p>
          </div>
          <article className="prose mb-52 prose-emerald md:prose-lg lg:prose-xl dark:prose-invert">
            <Markdown>{postObj.content}</Markdown>
          </article>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

But, I don’t know how to use a *.mdx file in this manner.
If there hadn’t been a build error, it would have been the easiest way to implement this.